# Kubernetes User Interface

Tags: kubernetes

I was going through a Kubernetes tutorial on Youtube and found the following UI which demonstrates pod and service arrangements of Kubernetes cluster.How can I install this UI in my Kubernetes setup?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In order to use this UI, go to the [saturnism/gcp-live-k8s-visualizer](https://github.com/saturnism/gcp-live-k8s-visualizer) GitHub repo and follow the steps, there.

Comment: Thank You. I followed the steps and managed to go to the page by http://localhost:8001/static/ but only thing I can see is a box that represents the node. I can't see services and pods that are actually available in my setup.

Answer (score 2):

The code for that UI is from https://github.com/brendandburns/gcp-live-k8s-visualizer.

Comment: Isn't that the same repository mentioned in  previous answer?

Comment: Nope, the one mentioned above is a fork of Brendan's repository.

Comment: Thanks. But it still is not working for me. I reported a issue https://github.com/brendandburns/gcp-live-k8s-visualizer/issues/6

Comment: From what I recall, the visualizer expects some specific tags to be on the pods / services for them to be displayed. It was built for a demo and I don't think it was generalized to work on arbitrary deployments.

Answer (score 0):

> the visualizer expects some specific tags to be on the pods / services for them to be displayed. It was built for a demo and I don't think it was generalized to work on arbitrary deployments

As Robert Bailey pointed out, the versions of brendendburns and saturnism are not generealized scripts, but require little modifications on your resource labels (such as labeling things with "name" or "uses").

Maybe this version can help you:
https://github.com/0ortmann/k8s-visualizer
It features minimalistic configuration options. You can configure labels you want the script to use. You do not need to change your actual setup.
Please contact me if you run into issues.